# In a Horizontal ListView, How to Set the Height of Items Individually?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to achieve something like that:

[image]

ListView code:

```
return Container(
         height: someHeightValue,
         child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: itemsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ItemWidget(itemsList[index]);
                  },
                )
       );
```

ItemWidget code:

```
return Container(
         height: someHeightValue, //Changing depending on the item.
         color: Colors.pink,
         child: Text('Item'),
       );
```

The problem is that the items is all stretched to the ListView height, and they ignore their height values.

Comment: whats the problem you are facing ?

Comment: @VilsadPP The problem is that the items is all stretched to the ListView height, and they ignore their height values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Center()` widget as below . It will set custom height & width to your widget.

```
return Container(
         height: someHeightValue,
         child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: itemsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Center(child:ItemWidget(itemsList[index]),);
                  },
                )
       );
```